# Generic inline and block level HTML element for styling

Tags: html, css

Is there an HTML element I can use to wrap other content in order to style it without affecting layout (e.g. to set the background colour) without knowing in advance whether the content is inline or not?

For example consider this HTML:

```html
<p>This is a paragraph with some text in it</p>

<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

If I want to make `Some text` yellow by wrapping it like this:

```html
<p>This is a paragraph with <yellow>some text</yellow> in it</p>

<yellow>
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</yellow>
```

Then what should I use for `<yellow>`?

You might say "use `<div>`" but that will break the paragraph *even with `display: inline`*.

The closest I can get is `<span>` with `display: inline-block`.

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph with <span class="yellow">some text</span> in it</p>

<span class="yellow">
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</span>
```

However this actually does affect layout (it moves the bullet to the bottom):

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px">
<ul>
  <li><span class="yellow">some text blah blah blah</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Is there an element that *really* doesn't affect layout?

Comment: No. All elements will affect layout in some fashion. You just have to decide how you want it affected.

Comment: But why do you need the element in the first place. That's what css is for?

Comment: Fair enough. I also realised in this case I can use `.yellow > *` to set the background colour and then it can just be a `<span>`.

Comment: It would be very complicated to add CSS to all the child elements/text in my case (this is in generated HTML, not hand-written).

Answer (score 0):

You could set your styling element as block by default and add a css declaration that makes it inline when it's a child of a block level element.

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}

p > .yellow,
li > .yellow {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph with <span class="yellow">some text</span> in it</p>

<span class="yellow">
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</span>

<div style="width: 100px">
<ul>
  <li><span class="yellow">some text blah blah blah</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

One other suggestion I'd make would be to use a [`mark`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) tag instead of `span`, since it's more semantically correct for highlighting (if that's what your actual use case is).

Comment: I don't think that will work but feel free to have a go.

Answer (score -2):

Although it is bad practice, you could create a custom tag in your CSS to apply these styles.
CSS for tag:

```
tagname {
styles go here
}
```

Then use the tag in HTML:

```
<tagname>hello</tagname>
```

Don't add a # or a . in front of the name in CSS. In HTML, these styles will be applied to all the contents in between the tags.

Comment: This appears to behave exactly the same as `<span>`.

Comment: You could add display attributes as you want. The only advantage is that you don't have to try to override span. dispaly:inherit; should make it have the same display as the parent.

Comment: Unfortunately all of your suggestions work in some cases but not others. I was after a generic solution that would work in all cases.